# Can't figure out responsive cards in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers, multiple-columns

I just built a new site from scratch using Bootstrap 4. I created a fluid container, then into that I inserted a Grid Row with 8 columns, and into each of these 8 columns I inserted a card with images.

Everything looked fine until I realized that it isn't responsive. In fact at xl the cards display at 4 in a row, but at lg the cards all stack vertically as if viewing on a phone.

Try as I might, I can't get the cards to be responsive no matter how much I play with the col classes.

Can someone help me to get this thing responsive? Basically I'd like the cards 4 across at xl (that's what they're doing now), 3 across at lg, and 2 across at md, sm, and xs. Again, right now it's displaying at 4 across at xl and only 1 across (stacking vertically) at all other sizes.

This is my first time here and hopefully after I type this I can include some code. Much appreciated.

Code example:

```
 <div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!--Image Grid-->
    <div class="row"> 
      <!--Real people Reel-->
      <div class="col-xl-3">
        <div class="card col-md-4 col-xl-12"> <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/university_hospital_network.jpg" alt="Real people Reel"> </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Real People Reel</h5>
          <p class="card-text text-open-sans">Your greatest and most credible asset.</p>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End Real People Reel--> 

      <!--University Hospital Newark-->
      <div class="col-xl-3">
        <div class="card col-md-4 col-xl-12"> <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/surgeons.jpg" alt="Real people Reel"> </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">University Hospital Newark</h5>
          <p class="text-open-sans">Medical accuracy... expert compliance, clearances and licensing expertise.</p>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--End University Hospital Newark-->
```

Comment: [ask]..........

Answer (score 0):

I think each "item" in a row, insert responsive class to there like that.

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
    <!--Image Grid-->
    <div class="row"> 
        <!--Real people Reel-->
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6"> <!-- add new class here -->
            <div class="card"> <!-- remove class here -->
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/university_hospital_network.jpg" alt="Real people Reel"> </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Real People Reel</h5>
                <p class="card-text text-open-sans">Your greatest and most credible asset.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Real People Reel--> 

        <!--University Hospital Newark-->
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="images/surgeons.jpg" alt="Real people Reel"> </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">University Hospital Newark</h5>
                    <p class="text-open-sans">Medical accuracy... expert compliance, clearances and licensing expertise.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End University Hospital Newark--> 
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way, visit W3School for more information about [Bootstrap 4 grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

So I hope it can help you.